# Locust Performance different from time() function

Tags: performance-testing, locust

I wrote a FastAPI and try to perform load tests using different tools. I have found that the performance from Locust is vastly different from time() python function:

- Locust shows min=17ms, max=2469ms, 99%=2000ms
- time() function shows min()=3ms, max=1739ms

Can someone please shed a light on why is that? Which one is more accurate?

---

Below are my programs:

**Fast API Function:**

```
app = FastAPI()

@app.post('/predict/')
def predict(request: PredictRequest):
    logger.info('Invocation triggered')
    start_time = time.time()
    response = adapter.predict(request.dict())
    latency_time = (time.time() - start_time) * 1000
    latency_logger.info(f'Predict call latency: {latency_time} ms')
    return response
```

**Locust parameters:**
`-u 500 -t 10 -r 500`

**Locust File:**

```
class User(HttpUser):
    wait_time = between(1, 2.5)
    host = "http://0.0.0.0:80"

    @task
    def generate_predict(self):
        self.client.post("/predict/",
                         json={"cid": [],
                               "user_id": 5768586,
                               "store_ids": [2725, 2757],
                               "device_type": "ios"},
                         name='predict')
```

**Locust Output:**
[image]

Comment: at what rate are you calling that function in the non-locust test? Dont do uber-fast ramp up (-r above say 50) if you want accurate results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locust and time are measuring two different things. time is measuring how long it takes to run only your `adapter.predict` function, server side. Locust measures the time it takes a client to get a response from your server route, which includes not only your `adapter.predict` call but also who knows what all else before and after that. "Which is more accurate" depends on what it is you're trying to measure. If you just want to know how long it takes to call `adapter.predict`, then time will be more accurate. If you want to know how long it takes a client to get the results of your `/predict` route, Locust is more accurate.